# Adding point in Open Layers and it's being drawn few pixels below actual position of a pointer click coordinates

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm newbie to Open Layers and a beginner to JS.
I'm trying to add a point in place where I click on the map. So far I've got it working but but added points are 'moved' few pixels from an actual point of click - no matter of zoom. They're always placed few pixels below.
It's probably a noobie mistake but can't really think even where to look for the cause here.

went through css files and nothing that could be a suspect here

`````
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([19.90, 50.06]),
          zoom: 10
    }),
    layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
         ],
    target: 'map'
});

var markerStyle = new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Icon({
     anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
     size: [52, 52],
     offset: [52, 0],
     opacity: 1,
     scale: 0.35,
     src: 'dot.png'
     })
});

var marker = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
     ol.proj.fromLonLat([19.95, 50.08])),
     style: markerStyle
});

var marker2 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([19.99,50.09])),
    style: markerStyle
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [marker, marker2],
    style: markerStyle
});

var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
});


map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);

map.on('click', function(evt){

  console.log(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));

  var pointCoords = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  var markerX = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
      ol.proj.fromLonLat(pointCoords)),
      style: markerStyle
    });

    vectorSource.addFeature(markerX);

});  ````
`````

Comment: It is likely to be a styling issue, especially if your are using icons.  Can you include your `markerStyle` setup in your code sample?

Comment: I just realized than the further from the top I click, the bigger difference is between point location - where it is and where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thnx for response - it probably lead me in right direction. I've played with markerStyle and then it turned out that on my small monitor when map size reached below some point there was a problem described. When resized it a little bit - it went away. Sorry for trouble and thnx to @Mike for reaching out.